# VScode not showing errors in real time

Tags: visual-studio-code, c, error-correction

Is there any way to set VScode in a way that it shows errors in real time? So far I can only see them after compiling.

I'm running VScode with WSL and I have C/C++ themes installed.

I already made sure that C_Cpp: Error Squiggles is enabled.

Here is the content of my "c_cpp_properties.json" file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Comment: `Is there any way?` .. compile from the integrated terminal?  That's a way.

Comment: By real time I mean while coding without having to compile.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to have static code analysis setup to lint your code. With the C/C++ extension [installed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack) you can do this.

Open the command palette and type `C/C++: Run Code Analysis on All Files` and click the cog to open that setting

From here you can map `Ctrl+S` to run this when you save the file manually.

OR

you could add `"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.runAutomatically": true` to the `settings.json` file